# UnderscoreJs, Array iteration issue.. returning multiple result

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, arrayiterator

I am using a underscore array iterator to manipulate a object. the result should be need to return as single time, But i am getting multiple time, as like my array length. how to correct this?

here is my function:

```
var ValidPaths = {
        "green":{
            "url":"greenController.js",
            "lightgreen" :{
                "url":"lightGreenController.js",
                "floragreen":{
                    "url":"floragreenController.js",
                    "ultragreen":{
                        "url":"floragreenController.js",
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

var path = "green",
    subPath = 'lightgreen/floragreen';

var paths = [path].concat(subPath.split('/')),
    arr = [],prePath=ValidPaths;

             function pathFinder (path,i){
                if(prePath[path]){
                    arr.push({"label":path,"url":prePath[path]['url']});
                    prePath = prePath[path];
                } else{
                    console.log("there is no path like " + path + "in ValidPaths");
                }
                return arr;
            }

            var breadCrumb = _.map(paths, function(root,i){
                return pathFinder(root,i);
            });

            console.log("breadCrumb", breadCrumb); // giving me 3 arrays instead 1 how to solve this?
```

[Here is the Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/MRPqJ/)

Comment: Well, that's just what `map` does… Try not to use underscore, or make this really functional by using `reduce`.

Comment: meaning, instead of use "_.map" need to use "_.reduce" ?

Comment: Yes, basically. The `prePath` and the `arr` would be the accumulator variables